# How to solve Surefire "tests are skipped" and jacoco "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit5, jacoco

I wan to generate jacoco report but unfortunately maven is not running the tests and the report is not generated. when running mvn test the console shows the following -

```
--- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:prepare-agent (prepare-agent) @ xx ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\xxx\\xx\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.8\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.8-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\xx\\xx\\git\\xx-xx\\target\\jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ xx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 16 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ xx ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 33 source files to C:\xx\xx\git\xx-xx\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ xx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] Copying 20 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ xx ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 16 source files to C:\xx\xx\git\xx-xx\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ xx ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:report (report) @ xx ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.570 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-22T15:42:57+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I did a lot of adjustments in the pom.xml but still no luck. I have commented a few dependencies and tried to execute the same. I am not sure what exactly is going wrong here. The commented dependencies are alredy tried. My pom.xml looks like -

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>3.0.0-M5</version>-->
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <includes>
                        <include>/**/*Test</include>
                       <!-- <include> **/*test/java/*</include> -->
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                </executions>
                <!--<configuration>
                   <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024M ${argLine}</argLine>
                    <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>240</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
                </configuration>-->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
        <!--        <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*test/java/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*test/resources/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>-->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <!-- <phase>prepare-package</phase>-->
                         <goals>
                             <goal>report</goal>
                         </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- <execution>
                         <id>default-check</id>
                         <goals>
                             <goal>check</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <configuration>
                             <rules>
                                 <rule>
                                     <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                     <limits>
                                         <limit>
                                             <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                             <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                             <minimum>0.60</minimum>
                                         </limit>
                                     </limits>
                                 </rule>
                             </rules>
                         </configuration>
                    </execution>-->
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
```

Most of the solutions that are provided in the stackoverflow are already tried and tested but so far no luck.

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: I am using java 11 in Intellij and Java_home is set to java 8.

Comment: And maven version?

Comment: Maven 3.6.3 in IntelliJ

Comment: First post the full pom file and also how you are calling Maven... apart from that the configuration for that project looks strange... also why using an old Maven version?  Also a lot of the given plugins are old...

Comment: @Jeet Have you tried it with the below code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by updating your existing plugin in `pom.xml` with the below code and it is working fine in my local with java 1.8 and maven version higher than 3.0 in a spring boot application.

**Plugin for jacoco report:**

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```